# How can I look for both folders and files in VS Code?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

I come from JetBrains, and when I want to look for a folder or a file, I simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>:

### Look for a folder:

[image: Look for folder]

### Look for a file:

[image]

In JetBrains, after selecting a folder, the explorer navigates to it.

Now, in Visual Studio Code, when  I look for a file, I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. But it seems like I can't look for a folder.

I found a partial solution that can look for folders in the project explorer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> but it doesn't seems to work completely.

Is there a way to tell VS Code to include folders in the searchbox?

Answer (score 0):

No, but there are 2 alternatives you might be interested in.

- [Mini Search in Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WACzl.png), By pressing <kbd>/</kbd> in Explorer, then type search text (Only works with expanded folders)
- [Reveal in Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5VkD.png), By opening a file in search results, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> reveals folder structure in Explorer.